# arcpy clip_managment migration from arcpy 10.1 to 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, clip

i've created script using arpy with arcgis 10.1. One of the goal is to clip raster via shp file, which contains one feature. it worked perfect.
after migration to arcgis 10.2 i've noticed some problem. result of clipping raster in exact shape of feature. it is just clip to extent of clipping feature.

```
arcpy.Clip_management(inFC, "#", cut_director + "/" + outFC, shp + "/" + shp_clip, "#", "ClippingGeometry")
```

i've tried to do clipping via arctoolbox (it  does the job) and then copy the process as python snippet but after changing input, output and clipping feature i received error.

thanks in advance for help

edit: i've found answer. when change nodata parametr from "#" (second one in code above) to "256" it works.

Comment: Please consider adding your solution as an answer, so that this question can be considered resolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the issue.

I just has to change the `nodata` parameter from "#" (second one in code above) to "256".

After doing this, the code works.